# Run functions recursively

Tags: function, plsql

I have 2 function **function1** and **function2**. 
Now I'm wondering how to run them recursively.

Maybe I will describe it:
Input of function1 is table of array from function2 output. Output of function1 is also table of array which is input for function2 and so on.

While function1 is returning some values then function2 should be execute with that values.
When function2 return some values then function1 should be execute.

Function1 and function2 should be execute until one of them return null. Is it possible to do in pl/sql? Could you give me some tips? How to correctly convey the variables?

EDIT:

Generally it should looks:

```
declare
tab2 num_array;
v_Return NUM_ARRAY;
v_Return2 NUM_ARRAY;
BEGIN
select ID bulk collect into tab2 from account;   
  v_Return := function1(tab2);
 if v_return is not null then  
  v_return2 :=function2(v_return);

  --and now iteration:
    if v_return2.count>0 then
      v_Return := function1(v_return2);
        if v_return.count>0 then
           v_return2 :=function2(v_return);
              if v_return2.count>0 then
                  v_Return := function1(v_return2);
                      if v_return..count>0 then
                          v_return2 :=function2(v_return);
                  -- and so on
END;
```

Of course I want to avoid doing something like that, can it be dynamically?

----edit 2

```
while(num=1)
loop
  if  v_return.count>0 then  
        num := 1;
        v_return2 :=function2(v_return);

            if v_return2.count>0 then
              num :=1;
              v_Return := function1(v_return2);

            else num :=0;
            end if;

  else num :=0;
  end if;

end loop;   
END;
```

Comment: Which function do you call first?

Comment: And what do these functions do apart from call each other?

Comment: first i will call function1 with some other defined table as input ( lets assume table1). and after call function2 and output of function2 as input for function1

Comment: its hard to explain exactly what do they do, first is looking for the hierarchy/tree base on id account from function2, and function2 search some others things base on function1 output

Comment: of course inside function1 is a condition which eliminate accounts which were processed before

Comment: Tony I updated my question, could you take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a simple loop?

```
loop
   v_return2 := function2(v_return);
   exit when v_return2.count = 0;
   v_return := function1(v_return2);
   exit when v_return.count = 0;
end loop;
```

Comment: I find out some other solution, I edited my post (edit2), Of course yours solution looks better : )